# wrong number or types of arguments in call to my procedure

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

hi I wrote this code to create a procedure to return a Boolean value based on the if conditions but when I execute it I got this error:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'DDPAY_SP'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

here is my procedure

```
create or replace procedure  DDPAY_SP (

donor_id dd_donor.iddonor%type,
pldgstatus out dd_pledge.idstatus%type,
monthplan  out dd_pledge.paymonths%type,
ret out boolean)
IS
begin

select idstatus, paymonths into
pldgstatus, monthplan from dd_pledge 
where iddonor = donor_id ;

if (pldgstatus = 10 AND monthplan >0)
then ret:= true;
else
ret:= false;
end if;

end;
```

and this how I execute it

```
 EXECUTE DDPAY_SP (308);
```

I didn't put much talk I hope it's clear enough for you

I read online it recommends me to check the naming also the data type which I did but nothing change

any ideas

Comment: Your procedure requires 1 input value and three output variables.  You only supplied the input value.

Comment: @BobJarvis but why then should I provide the outputs...and BTW the question is asking only for a Boolean (TRUE/FALSE) not the two variables but I declared them coz before that I got error I guess that was due to their absence so I just declared them. to run the SQL statement but I don't need to output them

Comment: so how can I write me execution statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need the second and third arguments you could declare those as variables in the procedure instead of arguments, as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DDPAY_SP(DONOR_ID IN  DD_DONOR.IDDONOR%TYPE,
                                     RET      OUT BOOLEAN)
IS
  nPayment_count  NUMBER;
BEGIN 
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO nPayment_count  
    FROM DD_PLEDGE p
    WHERE p.IDDONOR = DONOR_ID AND
          p.IDSTATUS = 10 AND
          p.PAYMONTHS > 0;

  IF nPayment_count > 0 THEN
    RET := TRUE;
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DD_PAY - exception: ' || SQLCODE || ' : ' || SQLERRM);
    RAISE;
END DDPAY_SP;
```

I've included an example of an EXCEPTION handler at the end of DD_PAY.  It's always a good idea to include at least this minimal handler so that in the event an exception occurs you'll get some indication of where the problem lies.

Because this procedure returns a BOOLEAN value, and BOOLEANs cannot (to the best of my knowledge) be used from SQL*Plus, you'll have to invoke it from a PL/SQL block, as follows:

```
DECLARE
  bRetval  BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
  DD_PAY(308, bRetval);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Returned value is ' ||
                       CASE bRetval
                         WHEN TRUE THEN 'TRUE'
                         ELSE 'FALSE'
                       END);
END;
```

Give that a try.

EDIT: rewrote procedure based on further information from later comments.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: I'm getting this one dude                                                                   ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.DDPAY_SP", line 20
ORA-06512: at line 4
01422. 00000 -  "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"
*Cause:    The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned.
*Action:   Rewrite the query or change number of rows requested

Comment: I have test it again but with different id_donnor value and I found if this value has only row in the dd_pledge it gives me 'anonymous block completed' only with neither true nor false.....but if the value has more than a row then the error occur????

Comment: sorry my bad the DBMS output window was not connected to my Schema thus I couldn't see the output.....but if the iddonnor has more than a row I'm still getting the "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"

Comment: @user2396035 : The problem is that more than one row exists in DD_PLEDGE for a given IDDONOR, something I couldn't have known.  No problem - I've rewritten the procedure to handle this situation.  Share and enjoy.

Comment: I test it and it's looks fine now...but one thing I found surprising when I test with different rows where idstatus =20 and paymonths=0 it gives me FALSE "it's what I expect" with all cases expect one case it gives me TRUE!!!!

Comment: Well, the procedure specifically looks for IDSTATUS = 10, rather than 20 as you mentioned in your last comment.  Perhaps this is part of the issue?

Comment: but as I observed all cases with IDSTATUS = 20, gives me correct Boolean value expect one case give me wrong value I wonder