# Pass a list of integers from C# into Oracle stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a oracle stored procedure which updates a table with the following statement.

```
update boxes 
set    location = 'some value'
where  boxid = passed value
```

I have a page where the user selects 100+ boxes and updates them with a new location value. Currently, I have to call the stored procedure 100+ times to update each box(by passing a boxid each time).

I want to know how I can pass a list of boxids from `C#` into the stored procedure so that I have to call the stored procedure just one time.

I am hoping to use a **where in(boxids)** kind of where clause in the update statement.

Please let know how can I achieve this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508240/how-can-i-supply-a-listint-to-a-sql-parameter

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032006/passing-an-array-from-net-application-to-oracle-stored-procedure?rq=1

Comment: What ADO.NET provider are you using? You could pass the numbers as an array, if the provider supports it. Oracle does support array parameters, check [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15515772/array-in-in-clause-oracle-plsql) on how to pass a list of values and due a proper `IN` query

Comment: possible duplicate of [OracleParameter and IN Clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541466/oracleparameter-and-in-clause)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oracle allows you to pass arrays of values as parameters. Borrowing from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15515772/array-in-in-clause-oracle-plsql) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541466/oracleparameter-and-in-clause) you can define an `INT_ARRAY` type like this:

```
create or replace type CHAR_ARRAY as table of INTEGER;
```

Then define your stored procedure as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE product_search(
        ...
        myIds IN CHAR_ARRAY,
        ...)
AS  
    SELECT ...
    ...
    WHERE SomeIdField IN (Select column_value FROM TABLE(myIds))
    ...
```

You can then pass the list of values by setting the [OracleParameter.CollectionType](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E15167_01/OracleParameterClass.htm#BABJEFCI) property  like this:

```
OracleParameter param = new OracleParameter();
param.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int32;
param.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
```

Comment: I think for proper operation you have to add `param.Size = boxids.Length;` befrore you execute the command.

Comment: @Wernfried you also have to actually set the `.Value` property, add the parameter to the `Parameters` collection, write a command text with the same number and names of parameters as those you pass - without looking at the code we can't really help

Comment: @gauravthakur post a new question with your code, schema and specific error. It's also rather hard to understand what you mean `I don't want to create it at schema level`. At what level do you want to define the type? Don't answer here, post a question explaining *why* you don't want to create a new type or table

Comment: what did you do for the Value problem? @gs_developer_user3605534

Comment: @masoudvali SO isn't a discussion forum and comments to answers are comments to answers, not replies to others. It's not Twitter either, you can't notify someone by putting their name at the *end* of a comment. What `Value problem`? If you pass the wrong number of arguments, you passed the wrong number of arguments. If you have a question, post a question

Comment: @masoudvali did the same what? There was no question, just a *comment* without information. As for the error message itself, it could simply mean there was a typo in the parameter names. Or the stored procedure was called with [more or fewer parameters than it actually has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737141/wrong-number-or-types-of-arguments-in-call-to-my-procedure). Or a wrong parameter type. Perhaps an *unrelated* parameter

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a new procedure, designed to handle a list of values.  An efficient approach would be to load the multiple values into a global temp table, using a bulk insert, and then have the procedure update using a join to the GTT.

A notional example would look like this:

```
OracleTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead);
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(insertSql, conn, trans);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("BOX_ID", OracleDbType.Number));
cmd.Parameters[0].Value = listOfBoxIds;   // int[] listOfBoxIds;
cmd.ExecuteArray();

OracleCommand cmd2 = new OracleCommand(storedProc, conn, trans);
cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

trans.Commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand your concern - the round trips will be taxing.

Unfortunately I don't have anything to test, but you can try 
[Oracle bulk updates using ODP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464616/oracle-bulk-updates-using-odp-net) 
or

-- edit1: go with Panagiotis Kanavos's answer if your provider supports it, else check below  --

-- edit12 as highlighted by Wernfried, long is deprecated. Another thing consider is max length varchar2: it doesn't scale on a very big set. Use the one below as the last resort. --

- changing your stored procedure to accept string
- implement [string_2_list](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:210612357425) in asktom.oracle.com.

  ```
  create or replace type myTableType as table of varchar2 (255);

  create or replace function in_list( p_string in varchar2 ) return myTableType
   as
       l_string        long default p_string || ',';
       l_data          myTableType := myTableType();
       n               number;
   begin
     loop
         exit when l_string is null;
         n := instr( l_string, ',' );
         l_data.extend;
         l_data(l_data.count) := 
               ltrim( rtrim( substr( l_string, 1, n-1 ) ) );
         l_string := substr( l_string, n+1 );
    end loop;

    return l_data;
  end;
  ```

  Above is early variant and splice to varchar2, but if you read more (including other threads) at that site
  you'll find more advanced variants (optimized, better exception handling)

Comment: Oracle has multiple collection types that allow you to pass a list of arguments without resorting to strings.

Comment: Oracle datatype `LONG` is deprected for ages! You should not use it in any new written code.

Comment: @Wernfried: below the code I've suggested to read the original article further for more advanced variant. I gave the initial version simply because link-only answer is not recommended in SO.

Answer (score 0):

Your PL/SQL block may look like this one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE YOUR_PACKAGE AS
   TYPE TArrayOfNumber IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
   PROCEDURE Update_Boxes(boxes IN TArrayOfNumber );

END YOUR_PACKAGE;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY YOUR_PACKAGE AS

PROCEDURE Update_Boxes(boxes IN TArrayOfNumber) is
BEGIN
   FORALL i IN INDICES OF boxes 
   update boxes  
   set location = boxes(i) 
   where boxid = ...;
END Update_Boxes;

END YOUR_PACKAGE;
```

The C# code you get already in answer from Panagiotis Kanavos